# custom Allocator compilation difficulties 2

Tags: c++, c++11, allocator

I am defining a custom allocator but I need to keep pointers of the allocator as offsets. As I change the pointer definition to a "size_t" type the code doesn't compile again with no apparent clues !
The need is to create a custom allocator where the memory is addressed in a "segment:offset" style and the address of the segment ( object ) is relocatable.

```
#include <bits/c++config.h>
#define _GLIBCXX_FULLY_DYNAMIC_STRING 0

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>

#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <limits>


typedef int32_t Token;
typedef unsigned char byte;

using namespace std;
template <typename T>
struct Allocator {
 public:

// http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4795/C-Standard-Allocator-An-Introduction-and-Implement

    typedef T value_type;

    typedef std::size_t pointer;
    typedef const std::size_t const_pointer;


    typedef value_type& reference;typedef const value_type& const_reference;

    typedef std::size_t size_type;
  typedef std::ptrdiff_t difference_type;

  template<typename U> struct rebind {typedef Allocator<U> other;};

    static const size_t heapSize=0x1000;
    static pointer freePos;
    static Token freeT;
    static byte m[heapSize];

    inline explicit Allocator() {freeT=0;freePos=0;}
  inline ~Allocator() {}
  inline Allocator(Allocator const&) {} // with explicit it doesn't compile

  inline pointer address(reference r) {return &r;}
  inline const_pointer address(const_reference r) {return &r;}

  //static inline pointer allocate(size_type n, typename std::allocator<void>::const_pointer hint = 0){ 
    //  pointer t=freePos;freePos+=n*sizeof(T);return t;
  static inline pointer allocate(size_type n){pointer t=freePos;freePos+=n*sizeof(T);return t;}


    static void deallocate(pointer p, size_type n){
    *(pointer*)((byte*)m+p)=(pointer)(n*sizeof(T));
    }

    static inline void deallocate(T* p,size_type n){deallocate((pointer)((byte*)p-m),n);}
    static inline void deallocate(const T* p,size_type n){deallocate((pointer)((byte*)p-m),n);}

  inline size_type max_size() const{ 
        return std::numeric_limits<size_type>::max() / sizeof(T);
    }
  inline void construct(pointer p, const T& t) {}
  inline void destroy(pointer p) {}

};

template <typename T>
bool operator==(Allocator<T> const &, Allocator<T> const &) { return true; }

template <typename T>
bool operator!=(Allocator<T> const &, Allocator<T> const &) { return false; }


using namespace std;

typedef     std::basic_string< char,std::char_traits<char>,Allocator<char> > String;

int main(){
String s("nice");
String t("very nice");
String u("good");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Doctor, it hurts when I do that.  Don't do that then.

Comment: Why would you want an explicit *copy constructor*?

Comment: Your `pointer` type does not satisfy the requirements for allocator pointer types. Take a look at [allocator.requirements] in the Standard. E.g. for a `pointer p`, `*p` must be well-defined.

Comment: More specifically: [allocator.requirements]/4 requires `pointer` to fulfill the `NullablePointer` requirements as well as the *random access iterator* requirements. You cannot fulfill those requirements with a mere offset, you could e.g. store both the pointer and the offset in a custom struct.

Comment: So what's the sense of having "abstraction" with pointer when it just means T* ? Ok I read the docs an I will never again define the pointer type as something different.

Comment: I didn't understood the "explicit copy constructor" question !

Comment: Here is an example of dyp's suggestion: http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/test/support/min_allocator.h  This link has something called `min_pointer`, which perhaps you could adapt to your set:offset requirements.  These would then become typedef'd as the `pointer` types in your allocator.

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis You cann add a (one) `@username` to a comment to send a notification to that user. -- About the explicit copy constructor: You have added the comment "with explicit it doesn't compile" to your code. A copy constructor that is `explicit` disallows reasonable syntax such as `Allocator<T> x; auto y = x;` (while `auto z(x);` is still allowed). It disallows any form of implicit copy, including pass-by-value.

Answer (score 1):

Keep the definitions of `pointer` and `const_pointer` the way the standard library expects it to be:

```
  typedef T* pointer;
  typedef const T* const_pointer;
```

Add a new `typedef`:

```
  typedef std::size_t offset_type;
```

Use `offset_type` instead of `pointer` in suitable places.

Here's a version that compiles and builds but produces Segmentation Fault at run time. I'll leave it to you to figure out that problem.

```
#include <bits/c++config.h>
#define _GLIBCXX_FULLY_DYNAMIC_STRING 0

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>

#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <limits>


typedef int32_t Token;
typedef unsigned char byte;

using namespace std;
template <typename T>
struct Allocator {
   public:

      // http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4795/C-Standard-Allocator-An-Introduction-and-Implement

      typedef T value_type;

      typedef T* pointer;
      typedef const T* const_pointer;

      typedef std::size_t offset_type;


      typedef value_type& reference;typedef const value_type& const_reference;

      typedef std::size_t size_type;
      typedef std::ptrdiff_t difference_type;

      template<typename U> struct rebind {typedef Allocator<U> other;};

      static const size_t heapSize=0x1000;
      static offset_type freePos;
      static Token freeT;
      static byte m[heapSize];

      inline explicit Allocator() {freeT=0;freePos=0;}
      inline ~Allocator() {}
      inline Allocator(Allocator const&) {} // with explicit it doesn't compile

      inline offset_type address(reference r) {return &r;}
      inline const_pointer address(const_reference r) {return &r;}

      //static inline offset_type allocate(size_type n, typename std::allocator<void>::const_pointer hint = 0)
      //  offset_type t=freePos;freePos+=n*sizeof(T);return t;
      static inline pointer allocate(size_type n){offset_type t=freePos;freePos+=n*sizeof(T);return (pointer)t;}


      static void deallocate(offset_type p, size_type n){
         *(offset_type*)((byte*)m+p)=(offset_type)(n*sizeof(T));
      }

      static inline void deallocate(pointer p,size_type n){deallocate((offset_type)((byte*)p-m),n);}
      static inline void deallocate(const_pointer* p,size_type n){deallocate((offset_type)((byte*)p-m),n);}

      inline size_type max_size() const{ 
         return std::numeric_limits<size_type>::max() / sizeof(T);
      }
      inline void construct(offset_type p, const T& t) {}
      inline void destroy(offset_type p) {}

};

template <typename T>
typename Allocator<T>::offset_type Allocator<T>::freePos;

template <typename T>
Token Allocator<T>::freeT;

template <typename T>
byte Allocator<T>::m[Allocator::heapSize];

template <typename T>
bool operator==(Allocator<T> const &, Allocator<T> const &) { return true; }

template <typename T>
bool operator!=(Allocator<T> const &, Allocator<T> const &) { return false; }


using namespace std;

typedef     std::basic_string< char,std::char_traits<char>,Allocator<char> > String;

int main(){
   String s("nice");
   String t("very nice");
   String u("good");
   return 0;
}
```